# Total no. of Transitive Relation on $A = \{a,b,c\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Calculation of total no. of Transitive Relation on $\displaystyle A = \left\{a,b,c\right\}.$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ First We will calculate Total no. of Relation on $A$, Which is $\displaystyle = 2^{3^2} = 512.$

Now We Will find Total no. of Relation which are Not Transitive.

and Then Use The Formula.

Total no. of Transitive Relation $ = $ Total Relation $-$ No. of relation which are Non- Transitive.

So We Will Calculate Total no. of Non-Transitive Relation.

$\displaystyle \left\{(a,b)\;,(b,a)\right\}\;\;,\left\{(a,b)\;,(b,a),(a,a)\right\}\;\;, \left\{(a,b)\;,(b,a),(a,a)\right\}\;\;,\left\{(b,c)\;,(c,a),(c,c)\right\}\;,\left\{(c,a)\;,(a,b),(a,a)\right\}.......$

Now I did not Understand How Can I Calculate no. of Non- Transitive relation,

Plz explain me

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a systematic procedure for this. Therefore I drew graphs with three vertices and an arrow for each related pair $(x,y)$ with $x\ne y$. I found nine types of graphs that can be extended to a transitive relation by adding some loops $(x,x)$. Some of these loops are enforced. It is up to you to count the number of labeled graphs for each type. My end result was $171$.

[image]